How come muxing to an mp4 file skips one of the frames I provide to it?
Background
In the past, I've created and even shared an example of how to create MP4 file from a series of Bitmaps, here, based on here, and I've also published the code on Github, here.
It seems to work fine with a single image, as such:
@WorkerThread
private fun testImage() {
    Log.d("AppLog", "testImage")
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("AppLog", "start")
    val videoFile = File(ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[0], "image.mp4")
    if (videoFile.exists())
        videoFile.delete()
    videoFile.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
    val timeLapseEncoder = TimeLapseEncoder()
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test)
    val width = bitmap.width
    val height = bitmap.height
    timeLapseEncoder.prepareForEncoding(videoFile.absolutePath, width, height)
    val frameDurationInMs = 1000
    timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap, frameDurationInMs)
    timeLapseEncoder.finishEncoding()
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("AppLog", "it took ${endTime - startTime} ms to convert a single image ($width x $height) to mp4")
}

The problem
When I try to work on multiple frames, and even just 2 frames, I can see that sometimes it skips some frames, making the video also shorter.
For example, this scenario that it should take 2 frames, each takes 5 seconds, yet the output gets to be 5 seconds instead of 10 seconds, and it ignores the entire second frame:
@WorkerThread
private fun testImages() {
    Log.d("AppLog", "testImages")
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("AppLog", "start")
    val videoFile = File(ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[0], "images.mp4")
    if (videoFile.exists())
        videoFile.delete()
    videoFile.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
//        Log.d("AppLog", "success creating parent?${videoFile.parentFile.exists()}")
    val timeLapseEncoder = TimeLapseEncoder()
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.frame1)
    val width = bitmap.width
    val height = bitmap.height
    timeLapseEncoder.prepareForEncoding(videoFile.absolutePath, width, height)
    val delay = 5000
    timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap, delay)
    val   bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.frame2)
    timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap2, delay)
    timeLapseEncoder.finishEncoding()
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Log.d("AppLog", "it took ${endTime - startTime} ms to convert a single image ($width x $height) to ${videoFile.absolutePath} ${videoFile.exists()} ${videoFile.length()}")
}

What I've tried
I tried to go over the code and also debug, but it seems fine...
Weird thing is that if I change the duration and also add more frames, it seems to be fine, such as:
This will produce 12 seconds video, when first 6 seconds is of one image, and the rest 6 seconds are of another image.
I also tried to have the equivalence to what I originally did, just in more frames:
for (i in 0 until 500)
    timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap, 10)
val bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.frame2)
for (i in 0 until 500)
    timeLapseEncoder.encodeFrame(bitmap2, 10)

This didn't create 5 seconds for each image at all...
I thought that maybe it's some issue with fps, but it's set fine in the code already, to 30, which is reasonable and it's probably above the minimal that's allowed for MP4 format.
So I tried to re-write the entire implementation. I thought it would help, but it has similar issues:
class BitmapToVideoEncoder(outputPath: String?, width: Int, height: Int, bitRate: Int, frameRate: Int) {
    private var encoder: MediaCodec?
    private val inputSurface: Surface
    private var mediaMuxer: MediaMuxer?
    private var videoTrackIndex = 0
    private var isMuxerStarted: Boolean
    private var presentationTimeUs: Long

    init {
        val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, width, height)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1)
        encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC)
        encoder!!.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        inputSurface = encoder!!.createInputSurface()
        encoder!!.start()
        mediaMuxer = MediaMuxer(outputPath!!, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
        isMuxerStarted = false
        presentationTimeUs = 0
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun encodeFrame(bitmap: Bitmap, durationInMs: Long) {
        val frameDurationUs = durationInMs * 1000
        drawBitmapToSurface(bitmap)
        drainEncoder(false)
        presentationTimeUs += frameDurationUs
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun finishEncoding() {
        drainEncoder(true)
        release()
    }

    private fun drawBitmapToSurface(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val canvas = inputSurface.lockCanvas(null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
        inputSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun drainEncoder(endOfStream: Boolean) {
        if (endOfStream) {
          //Sending end of stream signal to encoder
            encoder!!.signalEndOfInputStream()
        }

        val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
        while (true) {
            val encoderStatus = encoder!!.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000)
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            when {
                encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER -> {
                    if (!endOfStream) {
                        break
                    }
                }
                encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED -> {
                    //Output buffers changed
                }
                encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED -> {
                    if (isMuxerStarted) {
                        throw RuntimeException("format changed twice")
                    }
                    val newFormat = encoder!!.outputFormat
                    videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer!!.addTrack(newFormat)
                    mediaMuxer!!.start()
                    isMuxerStarted = true
                }
                encoderStatus < 0 -> {
        //                Unexpected result from encoder
                }
                else -> {
                    val encodedData = encoder!!.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus)
                        ?: throw RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer $encoderStatus was null")
                    if (bufferInfo.size != 0) {
                        if (!isMuxerStarted) {
                            throw RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started")
                        }
                        // Adjust the bufferInfo to have the correct presentation time
                        bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs
                        encodedData.position(bufferInfo.offset)
                        encodedData.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size)
                        mediaMuxer!!.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo)
                    }
                    encoder!!.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false)
                    if ((bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        //End of stream reached
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun release() {
        if (encoder != null) {
            encoder!!.stop()
            encoder!!.release()
            encoder = null
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer!!.stop()
            mediaMuxer!!.release()
            mediaMuxer = null
        }
    }

}


What's handled here is when all input bitmaps are the same resolution as the CTOR's parameter and not transparent. Also, the input resolution should match what the device can handle to encode.
To handle this too, there are 2 approaches:

Switch to WEBM which supports transparency, and then always fit to center.
Have some background to be set and always fit to center.

As for the resolution that you can handle, I need to check what's supported by something like this:
  MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mimeType);
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = codec.getCodecInfo();
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
        MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities videoCapabilities = capabilities.getVideoCapabilities();
        codec.release();

I didn't add this here because it becomes more complicated. I might add it to the repository, or prepare to have it.
This still has issues. Sometimes reaching 0 duration, or even when it's not, playing it might be like 0 duration.
The questions

How do I create the video properly, using this same API of adding one frame after another, with potentially a different duration and even different resolution or transparency?

Is there perhaps a better way to create video files from images, where you set the duration of each frame, one after another? A solution that doesn't require a large library and doesn't have a problematic license? I know of FFmpeg, but it's both large and has a license that seems not so permissive...



Decoding and encoding bitmaps can be resource-intensive, especially for large images. Resize or compress image or use FFmpeg4Android or similar library to encode it as MP4.

@BobSmith That's irrelevant to the question. I didn't get here some OOM exception or anything like that. Also it's a single Bitmap at any given time. Not multiple ones. It's encoding it as you progress, so it doesn't take much resources at all. Very hard to reach issues like that here. As for ffmpeg4android, does it have the ability to have bitmaps one after another, instead of from files? Also, what about the license?

Only just found your question. Can still try to help here or maybe you can ask a new Question about creating a custom MP4 from images without any libraries. I can show you how by just using arrays and integers.

@VC.One Sure show me here. Would be great and I will approve it if it works with all the tests that I've had. But the requirement is to have a function to encode one frame with its duration, and not to provide an array of frames (because that's inefficient in terms of memory usage and can reach OOM for large inputs).

Android Media3 Transformer is a perfect choice. Creating a video file from images is very easy:

Add dependencies:

    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-transformer:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-common:1.3.1")


Create an instance of the transformer:

    val transformer = Transformer.Builder(/*context*/ this).build()


Then, create a new composition from the media items sequence
(I used images from the asset folder just for demonstration):

    val imageFrameCount = 31
    val editedMediaItemList = ImmutableList.of(
        createImageEditedMediaItem("asset:///1.png", imageFrameCount),
        createImageEditedMediaItem("asset:///2.png", imageFrameCount)
    )
    val composition = Composition.Builder(
        ImmutableList.of(EditedMediaItemSequence(editedMediaItemList))
    )
        .build()

The function to create EditedMediaItem from an image:
@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
private fun createImageEditedMediaItem(
    uri: String,
    frameCount: Int,
    durationSec: Int = 5
): EditedMediaItem {
    return EditedMediaItem.Builder(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
        .setDurationUs(C.MICROS_PER_SECOND * durationSec)
        .setFrameRate(frameCount)
        .build()
}


Add a listener (it's optional, but we need to know when the transformation is completed) and start the transformer:

    transformer.addListener(object : Transformer.Listener {
                override fun onCompleted(composition: Composition, exportResult: ExportResult) {
                    super.onCompleted(composition, exportResult)
                    Timber.d("onCompleted: $exportResult")
                }
            })
    
    transformer.start(composition, File(cacheDir, "output.mp4").absolutePath)


Interesting! 1. How well does it handle special cases, such as different resolutions of frames, different duration of frames, frames with transparency ? 2. Is it possible to decide about the output file-format (MP4 when there aren't transparent pixels, WEBM when there are) only at the very end, when all frames were added? 3. Can I add Bitmap instead of Uri? 4. As you add a single frame anyway, what's the point&meaning of "frameCount"? Shouldn't it always be 1, while the duration is what I set to the frame?

See the edit to my answer. It seems the API is doing what I suggested, requiring each image to be displayed for an exact number of frame periods.

What do you mean by "exact number of frame periods" ? I don't understand what you claim and tried here and how it answers my questions. Suppose I wish to create a video of 3 frames: One takes 1 second, another takes 300ms, and another takes 2ms . Is it possible here?

Yes, each EditedMediaItem has its duration.
It's recommended to set the frame rate to 30 in the documentation. I don't know the exact reason.

For your question 1, is it possible that the delays you are assembling do not EXACTLY match the frame rate you are setting using format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate)? Video encoders are usually extremely picky about this.
I suggest making sure each original image is displayed for an exact number of frame periods.

Perhaps. Are you suggesting to make a very high framerate and always have the duration of each frame be based on it? I wanted to test 30 FPS for example. This means I can't have a frame of 1,000 ms (1 second) ? How would I fix this exactly?

I don't know what will make your software happy, and you might want to try that to see. My answer is based more on how the bit streams look and thus what constraints must apply to the encoding process.

I have clarified the answer. I trust the wording and intent is now clearer.

But what does it mean in code? If I set to 30 FPS, what are the requirements of how long each frame can be? If I want a frame to last a second, would I have to split the frame to ~31 to fit there? Meaning
30 frames, each of 33ms, and another frame of 10ms (because 33*30 +10 =1000) ? Have you tested this in my code?

If your frame rate is 30 FPS, you must display each frame for a multiple of 33.333333333ms, or 30 times for 1s,. No, I've not tested your code, but I spent years working on real-time video bitstream processing software.

That's quite a problem if I don't know the input frames durations, as each frame could be of a different length...  Might need a high FPS because of this. I wonder if it affects the output file though. Maybe if the encoding is of identical frames just because of annoying division as the FPS is high, the output video file won't be much different than a lower FPS with long frames.

Surely an "input frame" is a still image, and does not have a duration? Is your input a single image/frame or something else?

No, each image in a video has a duration. Otherwise you wouldn't have seen it. The term "frame rate" (AKA FPS) is about how many frames exist in one second, so from this you can know the duration of each frame.  An FPS of 2 means each frame takes 500ms. Here, though, we are talking about creating the video, so I ask if perhaps I should set a high FPS in the configuration and work with it somehow.

You misunderstood my point. A standalone image has no duration. You are assigning a duration for the image to be repeated in the video. This duration has to be a integer number of frame times, for whatever frame rate is in use. For example aat 25 FPS, you have to choose a multiple of 40ms.

So if the input is frames with various durations, I have to adjust each one's duration (round up/down) to fit something that would be a multiple of 1000/fps ? What happens if I set 1000 fps ? Would this affect the space the output video takes, even though most of the frames there would be identical? Would it be optimized , still?

if the input is frames with various durations, I have to adjust each one's duration (round up/down) to fit something that would be a multiple of 1000/fps ?
Yes, in principle, that is what I am saying. In practice, what I don't know is if 1000 is a usable FPS number. That is between you and the encoder and decoder(s) you are using :-)

How can I know what is a valid value for this? There is API to check what I can use?

As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with the API you are using. However, common frame rates in the film and TV industry include 25 FPS, 29.97 FPS and 30 FPS.
